# Laravel artisan migrate error with schedule

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to move my laravel project to another development system. Whenever I try to run `artisan migrate` to create all my tables I get a error for `clients table does not exist`

I found out this is due to my schedule method querying the table. When I come to deploy this project, how will I deploy without commenting out these lines? Or do I have the commands in the wrong place?

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    foreach (DB::table('clients')->select('id')->get() as $row)
    {
        $schedule->command('import:reports $row->id')->everyMinute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write something like this to check if table exists before runing foreach.

```
if (Schema::hasTable('clients')) {//Do Your foreach Here}
```

You also should write `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;` on top of the class to use Schema Facade.